# Linear model function lm() error: NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)

Tags: r, nan, lm, kaggle

Say I have data.frame `a`

I use

```
m.fit <- lm(col2 ~ col3 * col4, na.action = na.exclude)
```

`col2` has some `NA` values, `col3` and `col4` have values less than 1.

I keep getting

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

I've checked the mailing list and it appears that it is because of the `NA`s in `col2` but I tried using `na.action=na.exclude/omit/pass` but none of them seem to work. I've tested `lm` again on first 10 entries, definitely not because of the `NA`s. Problem with this warning is every google results seem to be pointing at `NA`.

Did I misinterpret the error or am I using `lm` wrongly?

Data is at [kaggle](http://www.kaggle.com/c/GiveMeSomeCredit/Download/cs-training.csv). I'm modelling *MonthlyIncome* data using linear regression (as I couldn't get a certain `glm` family to work). I've created my own variables to use but if you try to model *MonthlyIncome* with variables already present it fails.

Comment: `m.fit<-lm(col2 ~ col3 + col4 + col3*col4, data=a, na.action=na.exclude)` is much more readable for specifying your model

Comment: Without a reproducible example it is very hard to answer your question. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/567015 on instructions how to do this.

Comment: If you subset `a` for rows with no NA in `col2` and then run the `lm()`, do you still get the error?

Comment: For what it's worth, `~ col3*col4` is equivalent to `~ col3+col4+col3:col4` which is in turn equivalent to `~ col3+col4+col3*col4` (the last is harmlessly redundant)

Comment: Thanks Ben you are right, I misread a dot in my notes.

Comment: Not much point in posting a link to a datafile behind a login screen.  Meanwhile, try plotting your data to see if it looks even vaguely linear.

Comment: O dam I knew this would happen :S. But yea a smaller section of the data works just fine, the problem is when you use the all the observations. And linear regression is fairly logical given the data but definitely not something I want to use if I had better control over R.

Comment: @Pk.yd : get a dropbox and use the public links in there (www.dropbox.com). That's still the cleanest solution to share data I know of.

Comment: I signed up for Kaggle, and I can't replicate.  `a <- read.csv("~/Downloads/cs-training.csv")`; `names(a)[2:4] <- paste("col",2:4,sep="")`; `m.fit <-lm(col2~col3*col4,data=a)` worked fine for me.

Comment: Which columns are you using in the `lm` fit?  If you use the names in the header row in the file, it's clearer than `col2`, etc.  I've tried a few column combinations and can't reproduce your error.

Comment: So does `a <- read.csv("~/Downloads/cs-training.csv")`; `m.fit <-lm(MonthlyIncome~age*DebtRatio*SeriousDlqin2yrs,data=a,na.action=na.exclude)`

Comment: Urgh sorry everyone It seems the problem was Inf values in my custom coloumn, which I fixed after a good night's sleep... Once again very very sorry for wasting time.

Answer (score 39):

I know this thread is really old, but the answers don't seem complete, and I just ran into the same problem.

The problem I was having was because the NA columns also had NaN and Inf.  Remove those and try it again.  Specifically:

```
col2[which(is.nan(col2))] = NA
col2[which(col2==Inf)] = NA
```

Hope that helps your 18 month old question!

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Adding that in case you have some -Inf, make sure to make those NAs as well. That solved my problem.

Comment: For a one-liner: `col2[which(!is.finite(col2))] = NA`

Comment: As I said the root source of the problem is: log(0) = -Inf. The Log of Zero in such case fails to plot. If you consider your approach, you are effectively replacing data values and omit those rows as I understand with NA. If so, I guess you end up with no error but likely not the same box plot?

Answer (score 10):

You should have a read the book [A Beginner’s Guide to R](https://books.google.pl/books?id=bvwVXHhNQ-4C&pg=PA203&lpg=PA203&dq=Error%20in%20lm.fit%28x,%20y,%20offset%20%3D%20offset,%20singular.ok%20%3D%20singular.ok,%20...%29%20:NA/NaN/Inf%20in%20%27x%27&source=bl&ots=nrIGZpEgYk&sig=_NtXR4q59Yc2PwTg_WWclF8fKyk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFAQ6AEwBmoVChMIz_iXj8vxxgIVRoYsCh1-Xg1P#v=onepage&q=Error%20in%20lm.fit(x%2C%20y%2C%20offset%20%3D%20offset%2C%20singular.ok%20%3D%20singular.ok%2C%20...)%20%3ANA%2FNaN%2FInf%20in%20'x'&f=false) for a complete explanation on this. Specifically, it mentions the following error:

> Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset  =  offset, singular.ok =
>   singular.ok,...): NA/NaN/Inf  in foreign function call (arg 4)

The solution is to add a small constant value to the Intensity data, for example, 1. Note that there is an on-going discussion in the statistical community concerning adding a small value. Be that as it may, you cannot use the log of zero when doing calculations in R.

Answer (score 8):

I just suffered another possibility, after all posible `na.omit` and `na.exclude` checks.

I was taking something like:

`lm(log(x) ~ log(y), data = ...)`

Without noticing that, for some values in my dataset, x or y could be zero:
`log(0) = -Inf`

So just another thing to watch out for!

Answer (score 2):

I solved this type of problem by resetting my options.
`options(na.action="na.exclude")`
or
`options(na.action="na.omit")`

I checked my settings and had previously changed the option to
"na.pass" which didn't drop my y observations with NAs (where `y~x`).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the type of col2 (and all other variables)

```
col2 <- as.integer(col2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem. get the finite elements using

```
finiteElements = which(is.finite(col3*col4))
finiteData = data[finiteElements,]
lm(col2~col3*col4,na.action=na.exclude,data=finiteData)
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when my equivalent of col2 was an integer64 rather than an integer and when using natural and polynomial splines, splines::bs and splines:ns for example:

```
m.fit <- lm(col1 ~ ns(col2))
m.fit <- lm(col1 ~ bs(col2, degree = 3))
```

Converting to a standard integer worked for me:

```
m.fit <- lm(col1 ~ ns(as.integer(col2)))
m.fit <- lm(col1 ~ bs(as.integer(col2), degree = 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I inverted the arguments when calling `reformulate` and use the formula in my `lm` call without checking, so I had the wrong predictor and response variable.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to watch out for is using functions like log() or sin() make your x's and y's inf. eg. log 0 = 0 or sin(pi) = 0.

Answer (score 0):

This is what helped in my case. I parsed the data that already exclude NAs and INFs.

```
lm(y ~ x, data = data[(y != Inf & is.na(y) == FALSE)])
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you don't have any 0 in your dependent variable.