# Rcorr NA/Nan/Inf in foreign function call

Tags: r

I am reading in data features

```
data_features<-as.matrix(read.table("file.csv", header=TRUE,fill=TRUE));
```

Then converting to matrix and getting rid of Inf data using library "functional"

```
dd <-as.matrix(data_xls)
dd[apply(dd, 1, Compose(is.finite, all)),]
```

Then I am executing rcorr:

```
rcorr(dd)
```

And that results in:

```
Error in rcorr(dd) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
In addition: Warning message:
In storage.mode(x) <- "double" : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Without the use of Compose from functional, I would have this problem when 
creating a matrix. Currently, I don't have it when creating the matrix but 
afterwards when executing rcorr.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18624605/2886003) helps?

Comment: possible duplicate of [lm() NA/NaN/Inf error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415778/lm-na-nan-inf-error)

Comment: No, I used both but none of them worked.

Answer (score 2):

Normally it is because there are some cells in your data frame with NA, NaN or Inf values.
You can remove such value by using predicate `is.na(x)`, Page on `is.nan(x)` and `is.infinity(x)`.
[enter link description here](http://www.quora.com/What-does-the-error-message-NA-NaN-Inf-in-foreign-function-call-arg-6-mean-in-the-R-language)

Answer (score 1):

here's a late answer: I had the same problem and it ended up being the format of my numbers that was not accepted by the function. I had 1'203 instead of 1203 for ex. and that caused the error. Converting to normal number format worked. hope this helps