# R locating finite values in dataset

Tags: r, data-cleaning, infinite-value

I have a dataset where I have filtered out the NA values and plan to fit a general linear model to predict stuff.
However when I do this:

```
     model<-bayesglm(total_score ~ ., data=traint)
```

I get the following error:

```
     Error in lm.fit(x = x.star[good.star, , drop = FALSE] * w.star, y = z.star *  : 
         NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
```

Based on a previous post: [lm() NA/NaN/Inf error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415778/lm-na-nan-inf-error) , I am trying to eliminate the finite values of the dataset....

Having checked for such finite values with:

```
     summary(timesData)

     output too long to show
```

I can't find any symbol that tells me how to subset the data in such a way that I can filter out these finite values....

My attempt at doing this anyway is as follows:

```
    train<-subset(timesData, !is.finite(timesData))
```

Naturally, as I haven't specified a column I get:

```
    Error in is.finite(timesData) : 
     default method not implemented for type 'list'
```

I tried lapply:

```
    lapply(timesData, byrow=F, is.finite(timesData))
```

but

```
    Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
       2 arguments passed to 'is.finite' which requires 1
```

So overall my question is how do I find the values in the dataset which are finite when '*summary()*' doesn't reveal the columns where they reside and also how can I use *lapply* to then get rid of them?

My data is publicly available at kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/mylesoneill/world-university-rankings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something you can try, it's strange that `is.finite` and `is.infinite` don't support data frame though, since similar function like `is.na` does:

```
timesData[apply(timesData, 1, function(row) all(is.finite(row))),]
```

An alternative method would be to convert the timesData to matrix and then use `is.finite` and `is.infinite` both of which have been implemented for class "matrix":

```
timesData[rowSums(is.infinite(as.matrix(timesData))) == 0, ]
```

This should usually be faster than the `apply` method.

Comment: Just replace `"is.na"` with `"is.finite"` in `is.na.data.frame` and vuala - you have a method for data frames. :)  Probably why there isn't a method.  Too easy.

Answer (score 3):

```
     df = data.frame(
      a = c(2,4/0,5), 
      b = c(1/0,3,5), 
      c = c(4,3,5))
     df
        a   b c
    1   2 Inf 4
    2 Inf   3 3
    3   5   5 5

#which columns have infinite values  
 is.infinite(colSums(df))
    a     b     c 
 TRUE  TRUE FALSE 

#only rows with finite values
   df[is.finite(rowSums(df)), ]
      a b c
    3 5 5 5

#or with apply and all     
   df[apply(apply(df, 2,is.finite),1,all),]
      a b c
    3 5 5 5
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve it is to loop over the columns, and replace infinite values by some sensible value, such as zero or -1 (depending on your data) 
For example:

```
for (f in names(train)) {
  timesData[,f]<-ifelse(is.finite(timesData[,f]), timesData[,f], -1)
}
```