# Singular gradient error with R's nls / nlsLM

Tags: r, regression, non-linear-regression

I would like to do a non-linear regression with a logit function like [brian s. cheng](https://bscheng.com/2014/05/07/modeling-logistic-growth-data-in-r/), based on
[Fox & Weisberg](http://socserv.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion/appendix/Appendix-Nonlinear-Regression.pdf).

I wanted to go the [most pain-free way](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47802/whats-the-most-pain-free-way-to-fit-logistic-growth-curves-in-r) 
and went with `nls`, but got the error

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

I checked that I don't have any [NaN, Inf or similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415778/lm-na-nan-inf-error) and found that I have [`Singular gradient error`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13053/singular-gradient-error-in-nls-with-correct-starting-values). However I don't use zero-residue artificial data (as one should not). As it has something to do with the internals of `nls` I turned to [nlsLM](https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-better-nls/), but the error remains. What can I do?

My data is https://pastebin.com/iTXQcBzB

My code is

```
nlsLM(y ~ SSlogis(x, Asym, xmid, scal), mydata) % Error in lm.fit
nlsLM(y ~ theta1/(1 + exp(-(theta2 + theta3 * x))), mydata) % Singular gradient
```

The data provided is actually just a part and my complete code is more like

```
mydata %>%
  group_by(groupNr) %>%
  do(regmodel = nls(.$y ~ SSlogis(.$x, Asym, xmid, scal), ., 
     start = c(Asym = max(.$y), xmid = mean(.$x), scal = 1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need better starting values:

```
nls(y ~ SSlogis(x, Asym, xmid, scal), mydata, 
    start = c(Asym = max(mydata$y), xmid = mean(mydata$x), scal = 1))
```

giving:

```
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ SSlogis(x, Asym, xmid, scal)
   data: mydata
     Asym      xmid      scal 
2.304e+04 5.519e+00 3.065e-01 
 residual sum-of-squares: 477139282

Number of iterations to convergence: 8 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 5.271e-06
```

Comment: Seems like a step in the right direction, but now with my data (I have multiple datasets that are like this one  and  I need to do it for all of them) I get the error `Error in qr.default(.swts * attr(rhs, "gradient")) :NA/NaN/Inf in external Function call (arg 1)` I posted the code in the question to illustrate what I am doing.

Comment: I created a pastebin where the error appears: https://pastebin.com/ZiVxJQMk